# Calling Java webservice using Python requests

Tags: java, python, web-services, python-requests

I have a simple Java REST webservice -

```java
@GET
    @Path("/get1")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Status getstudent(Track track) {
        System.out.println("GET1 title = " + track.getTitle());
        System.out.println("GET1 singer = " + track.getSinger());
        Status status = new Status();
        status.setStatus_flag("success");
        return status;
    }
```

Track

```java
public class Track {

    String title;
    String singer;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSinger() {
        return singer;
    }

    public void setSinger(String singer) {
        this.singer = singer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Track [title=" + title + ", singer=" + singer + "]";
    }

}
```

Python request module:-

```python
import requests
title = {"title":"Best Songs","singer":"lucky"}
r = requests.get("http://localhost:8080/StudentService/rest/insert/get1",data=title)
print r.content
```

Error

```html
<html><head></head><body>
<h1>HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type</h1>
<HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
<p><b>type</b> Status report</p>
<p><b>message</b> <u>Unsupported Media Type</u></p>
<p><b>description</b> 
    <u>The server refused this request because the request entity is 
       in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested 
       method.
    </u>
</p>
<HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.41</h3>
</body></html>
```

Is there a way to create the entity object and send it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `params` to send URL parameters; you are trying to send a request *body* instead.

You need to alter your service to accept form parameters:

```
@GET
@Path("/get1")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Status getstudent(
        @FormParam("title") String title,
        @FormParam("singer") String sing) {
    System.out.println("GET1 title = " + title);
    System.out.println("GET1 singer = " + singer);
    Status status = new Status();
    status.setStatus_flag("success");
    return status;
}
```

Now you can send URL-encoded parameters:

```
params = {"title": "Best Songs", "singer": "lucky"}
r = requests.get(
    "http://localhost:8080/StudentService/rest/insert/get1",
    params=params)
```

Comment: @user1050619: Does your Java service expect a JSON request then?

Comment: Yes, it expects a JSON request now..I have edited the web method @consumes(to accept only JSON request) now...Still not working

Comment: @user1050619: I'm not familiar with Java REST servers; no idea if that would require a *POST* request instead.

Comment: @user1050619: looking at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html you should really use `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)` and `@FormParam` to specify the title and singer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add content-type and accept in headers. Like:

```
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"}
r = requests.get("http://localhost:8080/StudentService/rest/insert/get1", data=title, headers=headers)
```